# Can I get a German visa extension when my Blue Card expires?

Tags: working-visas, germany, blue-card

I am non-EU Asian (Graduate from Germany).

I have a Blue Card which is valid for 2 years; it expires in three months. My company told me that it will not extend my work contract at the end of these two years.

If I don't find another job within these 3 months, would I be able to extend my visa? What are the conditions that would allow for me to extend my visa?

Comment: First: Start looking for a new job now. Your new job needs to also qualify for the blue card (or you need to get a work visa, but the blue card makes your life easier). Then: If you've already studied in Germany for a few years you might be eligible for a better visa already. If you speak German, you can already get a settlement permit, which lifts your job restrictions (read: you could also legally work at ALDI) and is unlimited, while still being tied to §19a so your spouse can work.